# SwiftUI - How to make a selectable scrollable list?

Tags: list, swiftui, scrollview, selector, picker

I'm trying to make something like this:

before scrolling
[image: before scrolling]

after scrolling
[image: after scrolling]

Essentially:

1. The items are arranged in a scrollable list
2. The item located at the center is the one selected
3. The selected item's properties are accessible (by updating @State variables)
4. Ideally the scroll gesture is "sticky." For example, whichever item closest to the center after scrolling readjusts its position to the center, so that the overall arrangement is the same.

I've tried using a ScrollView but I have no idea of how to implement 2 and 4. I guess the idea is quite similar to a Picker?

I've been stuck on this for a while. Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you looked at `ScrollViewReader`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could detect the location of items to select the centred one.

```swift
// Data model
struct Item: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    
    var value: Int
    // Other properties...
    var loc: CGRect = .zero
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var ruler: CGFloat!
    
    @State private var items = (0..<10).map { Item(value: $0) }
    @State private var centredItem: Item!
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            if let item = centredItem {
                Text("\(item.value)")
            }
            
            HStack(spacing: -6) {
                Rectangle()
                    .frame(height: 1)
                    .measureLoc { loc in
                        ruler = (loc.minY + loc.maxY) / 2
                    }
                
                Image(systemName: "powerplug.fill")
                
                ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
                    VStack(spacing: 0) {
                        ForEach($items) { $item in
                            Text("\(item.value)")
                                .padding()
                                .frame(width: 80, height: 80)
                                .background(centredItem != nil &&
                                            centredItem.id == item.id ? .yellow : .white)
                                .border(.secondary)
                                .measureLoc { loc in
                                    item.loc = loc
                                    
                                    if let ruler = ruler {
                                        if item.loc.maxY >= ruler && item.loc.minY <= ruler {
                                            withAnimation(.easeOut) {
                                                centredItem = item
                                            }
                                        }
                                        
                                        // Move outsides
                                        if ruler <= items.first!.loc.minY ||
                                            ruler >= items.last!.loc.maxY {
                                            withAnimation(.easeOut) {
                                                centredItem = nil
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                        }
                    }
                    // Extra space above and below
                    .padding(.vertical, ruler)
                }
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    }
}
```

Detect location:

```swift
struct LocKey: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue: CGRect = .zero
    
    static func reduce(value: inout CGRect, nextValue: () -> CGRect) {}
}

extension View {
    func measureLoc(_ perform: @escaping (CGRect) ->()) -> some View {
        overlay(GeometryReader { geo in
            Color.clear
                .preference(key: LocKey.self, value: geo.frame(in: .global))
        }.onPreferenceChange(LocKey.self, perform: perform))
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the response. Just from looking at your code, it seems like it's what I'm trying to make. However, I copied and pasted your code and got a few errors. Specifically, I got a "Cannot declare entity named '$item'; the '$' prefix is reserved for implicitly-synthesized declarations" error at the ForEach section. Is this some issue on my part? Thanks!

Comment: That method of passing Bindings is limited to iOS 15

Comment: @softandwet Yeah, it's a SwiftUI 3 way. In SwiftUI 2, you can write `ForEach(Array(items.enumerated()), id: \.offset) { index, item in ... }` and use `items[index]` when wanting to change the value.